# symfony2 set value through getters

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, entity, getter-setter

I'd like to know if it is possible to create entities dynamically and persist them. For example I have

```
class Member {

private $adress; //OneToOne(targetEntity="Adress", inversedBy="Member", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
```

And a class Adress

```
class Adress
private $member //...
private $city // string
```

I want to set the values dynamically. I have every getter/setter name in a string (In this case `Member.Adress.City`, and a function that works like this (simplified)

```
$data = explode('.', 'Adress.City');
$entity = Object; //Here, $entity is an empty Member
$cursor = $entity;

//-1 is to target only getters, and not setters
for($i = 0; $i < (count($data) - 1); $i++) { 

    $getter = 'get' . $data[$i];
    $cursor = $cursor->$getter();
}

$setter = 'set' . $data[count($data) - 1];
$cursor->$setter($value);

$em->persist($entity);
```

Sadly, this doesnt work.. I can only set direct values, like `Member.Name`, but not relational entities. Is there a way to work this out ? Thanks !

Comment: The property access component may be of some use to you with this.. http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/property_access/introduction.html

Comment: It didnt work as i wanted, but it's way cleaner so im using it now, thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Run symfony2 cli command `doctrine:generate:entities` and it should create a setter and getter methods for relations as well. And then you can use them in your loop.

Comment: I have the good getters and setters in my entities, I just want to access them in a dynamic way. Like I could get "Member.Adress.City", or "Member.School.Class.Teacher.Adress.City" as input

Comment: Is your `address` an `ArrayCollection` type?

Comment: As it's a OneToOne relation, It's not an ArrayCollection

Comment: You're right, sorry, I'm stuck on one issue with many to many and I forgot. Any way don't you have `getAddress()` method?

Comment: in this example, I have Member->getAdress()->setCity(). But when I do a $em->persist($member), the newly created Adress entity is not persisted

Comment: Did you try with `$address = Member->getAddress(); $addres->setCity('Some City');`

Answer (score 0):

So i found a solution, in the main entity (here Member),  i updated the getter. I was doing something like

`If($this->adress == null) return new Adress()`

But it didnt add an Adress object in the property, thus working on a random Adress object. I updated it this way :

`If($this->adress == null) $this->adress = new Adress();
Return $this->adress;`